# Matching url with parameters to url with placeholders

Tags: java, regex, url

I am storing URL's patterns that contain parameter placeholders: `{param}` in them to identify where to insert params however if I store the URL's with placeholder patterns and pass a URL with parameters in it I don't know how to identify the original URL with placeholders. I am putting the URL's with placeholders in a map and so if I query the map with a URL that is identical to one that is stored except that the placeholders are filled in, then it is not found.

For example - in the map:

```
testurl/{param1}/{param2}
```

Then I want to check if the following URL is in the map:

```
testurl/1/2
```

Which it should find as the pattern is unique however I just have filled in the parameters.. Is there anyway I can achieve this with regex or other? I don't mind iterating through all URL's in the map and comparing but I just don't know how I could compare them

Answer (score 1):

You parameter values can be any string that doesn't contain a slash (`/`), so regex would be:

```
testurl/([^/]*)/([^/]*)
```

This will capture your two parameters.

It allows a value to be blank. Change `*` to `+` if that is not wanted.

Change to `testurl/(\d+)/(\d+)` if parameters must be integers. *(Remember to double backslashes (`\`) when inserting into a Java string)*

Comment: The above was just an example, it could be that there is something like this: testurl/branch/{param1}/{param2}/branch  etc. There is no particular order that every url follows, it's a url and the params can be anywhere as long as it's a valid url.

Comment: Which is why I gave you both the optional parameter version, the required parameter version, and the integer version. You can choose, for each parameter, which to use, or use any other regex that fits the parameter in question.

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late, but for future reference. You can use UriTemplate. For example

```
UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(url);
if(uriTemplate.matches(other.url)){
   //match
}
```